# как разделить коллекцию на части по n -штук Laravel

Tags: laravel

есть
$bannerWorks = BannerWork::all(); к примеру тут будет 7 шт обьектов

мне нужно чтобы оно разделено было по 6шт
т.е первые 6 в одном и 1 в другом который останется если будет в другом 5 значит 5 это для сладера

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `array_chunk()`

```
$bannerWorks = BannerWork::all();

$bannerWorks = array_chunk($bannerWorks, 6);
```

Для коллекции в Laravel есть метод chunk();

```
$chunks = $bannerWorks->chunk(6);
```

[документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-chunk)

Comment: @wantstudy добавил в ответ

Comment: нашел это только
chunk()

разбивает коллекцию на множество мелких коллекций заданного размера:

Comment: лайк поставил спасибо!

Comment: @wantstudy если вам помог мой ответ, то обозначьте его как ответ